# How can I remove this indentation

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

There's a little indent that's showing up in my model. Here's what it looks like.

[image]

That part is in the middle of a line of vertices that seem like they are all the same, but this is the only place that has the indent.

Here's what Edit Mode looks like:

[image]

All the blue lines have a Mean Bevel Weight of 1.

When I look at the mode in Object Mode, it shows the indent

[image]

I've applied Rotation and Scale. And Reversed Normals.

The problem seems to be something with the Subsurface modifier. If I turn it off, the issue goes away.

Any ideas of what to try?

Comment: It's too hard to tell from just that one angle, but likely either duplicate verticies (merge by distance to solve) or the side faces.